# Comments out of order after adding item to Go AST

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

The following test attempts to use AST to add fields to a struct. The fields are added correctly, but the comments are added out of order. I gather the position may need to be specified manually, but I've so far drawn a blank finding an answer.

Here's a failing test: http://play.golang.org/p/RID4N30FZK

Here's the code:

```
package generator

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "testing"
)

func TestAst(t *testing.T) {

    source := `package a

// B comment
type B struct {
    // C comment
    C string
}`

    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", []byte(source), parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    v := &visitor{
        file: file,
    }
    ast.Walk(v, file)

    var output []byte
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(output)
    if err := printer.Fprint(buf, fset, file); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    expected := `package a

// B comment
type B struct {
    // C comment
    C string
    // D comment
    D int
    // E comment
    E float64
}
`

    if buf.String() != expected {
        t.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Test failed. Expected:\n%s\nGot:\n%s", expected, buf.String()))
    }

    /*
    actual output = `package a

// B comment
type B struct {
    // C comment
    // D comment
    // E comment
    C   string
    D   int
    E   float64
}
`
    */

}

type visitor struct {
    file *ast.File
}

func (v *visitor) Visit(node ast.Node) (w ast.Visitor) {

    if node == nil {
        return v
    }

    switch n := node.(type) {
    case *ast.GenDecl:
        if n.Tok != token.TYPE {
            break
        }
        ts := n.Specs[0].(*ast.TypeSpec)
        if ts.Name.Name == "B" {
            fields := ts.Type.(*ast.StructType).Fields
            addStructField(fields, v.file, "int", "D", "D comment")
            addStructField(fields, v.file, "float64", "E", "E comment")
        }
    }

    return v
}

func addStructField(fields *ast.FieldList, file *ast.File, typ string, name string, comment string) {
    c := &ast.Comment{Text: fmt.Sprint("// ", comment)}
    cg := &ast.CommentGroup{List: []*ast.Comment{c}}
    f := &ast.Field{
        Doc:   cg,
        Names: []*ast.Ident{ast.NewIdent(name)},
        Type:  ast.NewIdent(typ),
    }
    fields.List = append(fields.List, f)
    file.Comments = append(file.Comments, cg)
}
```

Comment: I suspect you need to update the [Comment Map](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#NewCommentMap) for this to work correctly.

Comment: Here you can see some details of the actual and expected trees : https://play.golang.org/p/qv63Hu1xmP thanks to https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Fprint .

The main differences I see are `Slash`, `NamePos`, and `Obj` not set.
I tried to fiddle with the positions, but could not get it right...

Comment: This one has me stumped... It looks like there is some kind of other bookeeping that needs to be done, as I was able to get Slash and NamePos to match (offset by 100 notwithstanding) in this: http://play.golang.org/p/pQodZncMjA -- and even adding in AddLine and CommentMap doesn't seem to help: http://play.golang.org/p/GGj2eDwDF-

Comment: I have made some progress on this: http://play.golang.org/p/rOqcPnovsx  The tricks needed include: (1) Specifically setting the buffer locations including `Slash` and `NamePos`, (2) `token.File.AddLine` to add new lines at specific offsets, (3) Overallocating the source buffer so `token.File.Position` (used "under the covers") and `token.File.AddLine` don't fail range checks against the source buffer.  But this introduces a bunch of serialization warnings/errors because of the mismatched size of the new tokens and the underlying buffer size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this answer might be a little late. But for the benefit of others, I found a reference to this library in the following GitHub issue

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20744

The library is called **dst** and it can convert a go **ast** to **dst** and vice versa.

https://github.com/dave/dst

In **ast**, Comments are stored by their byte offset instead of attached to nodes. **Dst** solves this by attaching the comments to its respective nodes so that re-arranging nodes doesn't break the output/tree.

The library works as advertized and I haven't found any issues so far.

Note: There is also a subpackage called **dst/dstutil** which is compatible with **golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil**

Comment: Yes! I asked this question and eventually got so annoyed with there not being an easy solution I created the `dst` package. I'll accept this answer!

Comment: Haha, I should have realized that Dave was your GitHub handle.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I have gotten it to work.  As stated in my comment above, the main points required are:

1. Specifically set the buffer locations including the `Slash` and `NamePos`
2. Use `token.File.AddLine` to add new lines at specific offsets (calculated using the positions from item 1)
3. Overallocate the source buffer so `token.File.Position` (used by `printer.Printer` and `token.File.Addline` don't fail range checks on the source buffer

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "testing"
)

func main() {
    tests := []testing.InternalTest{{"TestAst", TestAst}}
    matchAll := func(t string, pat string) (bool, error) { return true, nil }
    testing.Main(matchAll, tests, nil, nil)
}

func TestAst(t *testing.T) {

    source := `package a

// B comment
type B struct {
    // C comment
    C string
}`

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
    for idx,_ := range buffer {
        buffer[idx] = 0x20
    }
    copy(buffer[:], source)
    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", buffer, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    v := &visitor{
        file: file,
        fset: fset,
    }
    ast.Walk(v, file)

    var output []byte
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(output)
    if err := printer.Fprint(buf, fset, file); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    expected := `package a

// B comment
type B struct {
    // C comment
    C   string
    // D comment
    D   int
    // E comment
    E   float64
}
`
    if buf.String() != expected {
        t.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Test failed. Expected:\n%s\nGot:\n%s", expected, buf.String()))
    }

}

type visitor struct {
    file *ast.File
    fset *token.FileSet
}

func (v *visitor) Visit(node ast.Node) (w ast.Visitor) {

    if node == nil {
        return v
    }

    switch n := node.(type) {
    case *ast.GenDecl:
        if n.Tok != token.TYPE {
            break
        }
        ts := n.Specs[0].(*ast.TypeSpec)
        if ts.Name.Name == "B" {
            fields := ts.Type.(*ast.StructType).Fields
            addStructField(v.fset, fields, v.file, "int", "D", "D comment")
            addStructField(v.fset, fields, v.file, "float64", "E", "E comment")
        }
    }

    return v
}

func addStructField(fset *token.FileSet, fields *ast.FieldList, file *ast.File, typ string, name string, comment string) {
    prevField := fields.List[fields.NumFields()-1] 

    c := &ast.Comment{Text: fmt.Sprint("// ", comment), Slash: prevField.End() + 1}
    cg := &ast.CommentGroup{List: []*ast.Comment{c}}
    o := ast.NewObj(ast.Var, name)
    f := &ast.Field{
        Doc:   cg,
        Names: []*ast.Ident{&ast.Ident{Name: name, Obj: o, NamePos: cg.End() + 1}},
    }
    o.Decl = f
    f.Type = &ast.Ident{Name: typ, NamePos: f.Names[0].End() + 1}

    fset.File(c.End()).AddLine(int(c.End()))
    fset.File(f.End()).AddLine(int(f.End()))

    fields.List = append(fields.List, f)
    file.Comments = append(file.Comments, cg)
}
```

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/_q1xh3giHm

For *Item (3)*, it is also important to set all the overallocated bytes to spaces (`0x20`), so that the printer doesn't complain about null bytes when processing them.

Comment: I think you've cracked it! Well done. I'm sure I'll have follow up questions as I add more functionality, but this is a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: This only works for this particular situation.  If there were more code with newlines after the `B` struct than the length of the newly added fields and comments, then the calls to `AddLine` would be ignored ([the impl.](https://github.com/golang/go/blame/go1.12.5/src/go/token/position.go#L137) has not changed for the last nine years).  See: https://play.golang.org/p/NsBL74Z5bb7  Additionally, adding comments at the bottom of the "file" make things go haywire...  See: https://play.golang.org/p/g2vKIPm1OUx